# Document Term Matric (dtm) - R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a document term matrix (dtm) of a corpus of 40 different texts. I am trying not to include words with more than 20 characters. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing `wordLenghts` as a control argument:

```
library(tm)
DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,control=list(wordLengths=c(1,20)))
```

From the documentation:

```
wordLenghts - An integer vector of length 2. Words shorter than the minimum word length wordLengths[1] or longer than the maximum word length wordLengths[2] are discarded. Defaults to c(3, Inf), i.e., a minimum word length of 3 characters.
```